# How do I generate CAPTCHA images for Perl without GD?

Tags: perl, gd, captcha

How can I generate a CAPTCHA image file in Perl? I tried to use GD::SecurityImage, but GD is [broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41317771/how-do-i-install-gd-for-perl). I found a site that uses 1000 pre-generated images and randomly selects one of them, but I didn't think that was a good solution. Most of the Perl modules require GD or GD::SecurityImage. I can't find any pure Perl solutions.

Comment: Are you asking how to make a hardly readable image that is machine save, or how to implement the process of authentication with the user? Do you have to build your own or is using an api and going with e. g. Google's recapcha an option? There is a good implementation for that on cpan and is has a clear api and a proven approach.

Comment: I want a library that generates image files. I'll do the authentication myself. I can't use recaptcha because it is web based and you can't extract the image only.

Comment: Well, there is Image::Magick of course, but there is also [Imager](https://metacpan.org/pod/Imager).